# How to increase resolution over actual pixel count by trading for quality?

Tags: windows-8.1, resolution

I wanted to develop on my notebook, but I miss the full HD resolution. I would like to fit more things on the screen. I realized, that when I used TeamViewer on my 1366 * 768 Px screen it was able to show a full HD resolution I was connecting to. It did not look very tasty, because it had to calculate how to show many pixels in less pixels, but I could read and work like this.

Is there any way I could simulate this resolution on my notebook? I do not care it will look bad, sometimes I just want the huge space it gives me trading for the imaging quality.

Is there a way to do this on Windows 8.1?

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this to your entire desktop, but some apps allow you to zoom out.

Comment: Is there an app that would allow this to happen to other apps? I want this with NetBeans IDE

Comment: Try ALT+scrollwheel to zoom in and out.

Comment: Yes, this works for the source code. But I want the whole NetBeans IDE to do this. I want the whole Windows to do this. I do not want just generally fonts to decrease in size..

Answer (score 1):

According to my knowledge - no.

When you connect remotely, there is some scaling done. But when you work on your notebook, the resolution is 1:1 to your real life, physical pixels. Buy new notebook, with higher resolution. That's why they are more expensive. They've got more physical pixels.

Comment: buying a new one wouldnt occur to me, thanks for a helpful answer. AFAIK Apple devices can do it, so I think that technologically it thus must be doable, I just do not know how.

Comment: Apple got this Retina display. It's just LCD display with pixels packed up really tight. That's all.
Simplifying you've got matrix made of 1366 x 768 pixels and every can shine in one colour at a time, which altogether gives you image. You can't double resolution by making pixels to display 2 colours at once.

Comment: I completely understand the concept of pixels. I know you can not show two colors on one. I do not mean new apple machines with retina display, scaling down is out of what I am asking for (because it is obvious). Scaling up over the available pixels is what I am interested in. I am looking for scaling the same way it is done remotely, but locally.